# What's the default command Jenkins executes for a Maven Job?

Tags: maven, jenkins, default

I set up a Maven Job on our Jenkins server and it's running fine. In the configuration, I only had to specify the pom file, no goal/command whatsoever.

I'd like to run the same build locally and build a profile for doing that. I want to see wether it's working just like the job on the server (so I can test locally before committing). I can execute Maven commands just fine, I just don't know what command I need to get the comparable output. What does Jenkins use as the default Maven command? mvn clean install?

[image: Edit: Picture of build configuration]

Comment: could you share a screenshot of the maven config on your jenkins that you are using. that can help get the details.

Comment: If you haven't defined a goal than nothing should be executed. So please recheck your jenkins configuration of the job if you have defined some goals etc. ?

Answer (score 3):

create an "execute shell" box, and there you can type the maven command, such as mvn clean install.

See below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Jenkins executes `mvn install` if a project is specified as a maven job without any goals and options configured. I can see all previous phases executed.

Also, the build does not fail when tests fail, so I suspect `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` is involved as well.

I agree with other answers that this behaviour is unusual and it would be more intuitive to offer a visible default command instead of executing a build if no goal is specified.